# How to make Stack scrollable horizontally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a graph and I want the side titles of the graph (the Y-axis) to stay fixed on the left side of the screen, and allow the graph to be scrollable horizontally. I've built the graph but I can't make it scrollable:
[image]

```dart
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                  child: SideTitles()),
              Container(
                //needs to be scrollable

                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /2,
                child: Stack(
                  children: graph,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

I've tried to wrap the Stack with a SingleChildScrollView, but then the graph just disappears. I also tried to wrap the Container with the SingleChildScrollView but then I get an overflow error because the parent is Row which is a Flex widget.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried ListView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal.

More info: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it by adding `clipBehavior: Clip.none` in the Stack and then wrapping it with a Container that has the same width as the graph, and finally wrapping that container with SingleChildScrollView()

```dart
return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
              height: graph.yHeight,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
              child: SideTitles()),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                width: graph.xWidth,
                child: Stack(
                  children: graph.graphList,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```